# Does a kubernetes master node contribute?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, cluster, nodes

Does the master node contribute processing power to the cluster? Can it? I am interested in making a small cluster from old computers at home and I want to know where I should put the most powerful one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your cluster will not schedule pods on the master node for security reasons. To schedule pods on the master you can use the taint command as follows:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Here are some useful links:

[Creating a single control-plane cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

[Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)